# ClickEvent on ImageButton in Android?

Tags: java, android, button

Is it possible to add a click event to an ImageButton?

Comment: I have similar code that works. In which function do you set the on click listener? I do it on the activity's onCreate()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is!
you can implement the onclick method like this

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("ImageButton", "Clicked!");
        }
});
```

pls read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) for further details

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Resources/Images/) demonstrating a `View.OnClickListener` applied to an `ImageButton`.

Comment: What directory are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, here is the sample code (and zip-file)

http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/Android-ImageButtons-in-ListView-with-RelativeLayout-AID589.aspx